# Repeating/"Periodic" Derivatives?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

We know that $Ce^x$ and $0$ are the two functions whose first derivative is equal to itself, but what about derivatives of a higher order? For example, the second derivative of $e^{-x}$ is equal to itself, but not the first, and the fourth derivative of $sin(x)$ is equal to itself.

In short, are there other examples of functions whose nth derivative is equal to itself, where $n>1$?

Thank you kindly!

Comment: see this discussion http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1646912/which-derivatives-are-eventually-periodic

Answer (score 2):

The second derivative of $ce^x+ke^{-x}$ is the same as the original function, same goes for $\cosh(x)$ and $\sinh(x)$.

The third derivative of $e^{\omega x}$ is the same as the original function.